# Sharepoint mobile view issue

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sharepoint-2016

There are two sharepoint 2016 servers - local (for testing purposes) and production. All the updates are installed on both servers.

On local server the mobile view works fine, but on production following JS error appears:

```
touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SuiteVersion' of undefined
at Object.RetrieveMobileSuiteNavData (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at init (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at new SharePointSuiteNav (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at initSuiteNav (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at SharePointAppBar.Initialize (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at HostAppBar.Initialize (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at init (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at new SPTouchApp.AppBarController (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at Object.buildAppBarController [as builder] (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
at initializeUiControllers (touchapp.js?rev=3rU9Jr5OtqOHAouuUOO75g%3D%3DTAG0:1)
```

After investigation I found that HTML generated by "/_layouts/15/touchapp.aspx" is different on local and production server. On local server it contains following string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(){window.CommonSuiteNavData = {Scripts: ["/_layouts/15/mylinks.js?rev=HjKTiRHbpPJBEU6OeYZGyw%3D%3DTAG0"],...
```

On production server, the HTML does not contain this string. I think this is a cause of mentioned JS error. Also we found that on local Sharepoint the "mylinks.js" is being loaded by browser, and on production the browser does not load this script.

Please help me understand why two servers generate different HTML and/or how to determine cause of mentioned JS error.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound strange, but check for settings differences between your environments for the ***User Profile Service*** (UPS).  We were seeing similar behaviour in our non-prod environment recently and, after [finding this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4033897/mobile-view-breaks-if-upsa-association-is-gone-sharepoint-2016), we became aware that the Out of Box Mobile View for Team sites is dependent on the UPS.

In our case all we had to do was grant everyone permissions in the User Profile Service:

1. Central Admin > Service Apps > User Profile Service Application >
   Manage User Permissions
2. Grant '*Everyone*' permission to **Follow
   People and Edit Profile** and **Use Tags and Notes**

Comment: technically the error says that the user profile association (proxy) was removed and the work around is to deactivate mobile view... jezzzzzzzzzz